# Does this circuit convert sinewaves to square waves?

Tags: diodes, homework, sine, square

As part of a graded assignment on diodes, I was given this question.
[image: Text]
I ended up designing this circuit :-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feiAYV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I only got partial credit for the circuit. The official solution was :-
[image: Text]

With each of the zener diodes having a breakdown voltage of \$2.5\,\text{V}\$.
I want to ask before I challenge the grading. Will my circuit also work?

Comment: "There also is a resistor in series with the sources which isnt shown" - Why isn't it shown? You drew a circuit (+1) but then you didn't supply the whole circuit, which contains very relevant information to your question? (-1)

Comment: Edited the circuit to add the resistor.I am sorry it wasn't there before, I forgot to add it while drawing and didn't know how to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Zener diode works as a normal diode in forward biasing and works as voltage regulator in reverse biasing.

Since the diodes used in your problem are **ideal**, you can consider them as **short** in forward bias and as **voltage drop** of \$ 5 \, \text{V}\$ in reverse bias.

So I think you should remove the voltage drop you made, replace it with a short circuit and the circuit will work but you should notice that it will produce square wave which has value of \$5\,\text{V}\$ in the first half cycle and value of \$-5\, \text{V}\$ in the second half cycle.

Adding a  generic diode for the output of your circuit will rectify the output signal and make the peak value to be zero in the second half cycle.